# Stored Function - Error #1064 - Backtick/Tick?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I have following SQL code produced:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION flighttime (p_arrival(DATE), p_departure(DATE))
RETURNS CHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_hour INT;
    DECLARE v_minute INT;
    DECLARE v_htext CHAR(10);
    DECLARE v_mtext CHAR(10);
    DECLARE v_flighttime CHAR(50);
    DATEDIFF(minute, p_departure, p_arrival) AS v_minute;
    v_hour = v_minute/60;
    v_minute = v_minute-(v_hour*60);

    IF v_hour<2 AND v_minute<2 THEN SET v_htext=' hour and ' AND v_mtext=' minute';
    ELSEIF v_hour<2 AND v_minute>1 THEN SET v_htext=' hour and ' AND v_mtext=' minutes';
    ELSEIF v_hour>1 AND v_minute<2 THEN SET v_htext=' hours and ' AND v_mtext=' minute';
    ELSE SET v_htext=' hours and ' AND v_mtext=' minutes';

    SET v_flighttime = CONCAT(v_hour, v_mtext, v_minute, v_mtext);
    RETURN v_flighttime;
END

$$
DELIMITER;
```

**Correction:**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION flighttime (p_arrival DATETIME, p_departure DATETIME)
    RETURNS CHAR(70)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_hour INT;
    DECLARE v_minute INT;
    DECLARE v_htext CHAR(15);
    DECLARE v_mtext CHAR(15);
    DECLARE v_flighttime CHAR(70);
    SET v_hour = HOUR(TIMEDIFF(p_departure, p_arrival));
    SET v_minute = MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(p_departure, p_arrival));
    IF v_hour<2 AND v_minute<2 THEN 
        SET v_htext = ' hour and ';
        SET v_mtext=' minute';
    ELSEIF v_hour<2 AND v_minute>1 THEN 
        SET v_htext=' hour and '; 
        SET v_mtext=' minutes';
    ELSEIF v_hour>1 AND v_minute<2 THEN 
        SET v_htext=' hours and ';
        SET v_mtext=' minute';
    ELSE 
        SET v_htext=' hours and ';
        SET v_mtext=' minutes';
    END IF;

    SET v_flighttime = CONCAT(v_hour, v_htext, v_minute, v_mtext);

    RETURN v_flighttime;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

But I get following Error-Message in phpMyAdmin 3.5.2.2:

> `1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your         MySQL server version for the right syntax
>   to use near '(DATE), p_departure(DATE)) RETURNS CHAR(50) BEGIN DECLARE
>   v_hour INT; DECLAR' at line 1`

I have had 1064 errors before and was mostly able to solve them by using back ticks ` or normal tics '.  Unfortunately this time it hasn't helped.

The goal of this function is to calculate the difference between two dates and give this difference back in hours and minutes. Also to differentiate between singular and plural.

I would appreciate it if anyone has a solution or a clue for me how to solve this problem.

Thanks for the help. It is solved now (I had also to change DATE to DATETIME :) )

Comment: This question relates to an important syntactic detail that occasionally arises over the normal course of use of MySQL, so I nominate it for re-opening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have invalid declaration. it should be

```
CREATE FUNCTION flighttime (p_arrival DATE, p_departure DATE)
....
```

then another error will rise soon because of the invalid setting of value, you should use `SET`

```
SET v_minute = DATEDIFF(minute, p_departure, p_arrival);
SET v_hour = v_minute/60;
SET v_minute = v_minute-(v_hour*60);
```

full code,

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION flighttime (p_arrival DATE, p_departure DATE)
RETURNS CHAR(50)
BEGIN
    DECLARE v_hour INT;
    DECLARE v_minute INT;
    DECLARE v_htext CHAR(10);
    DECLARE v_mtext CHAR(10);
    DECLARE v_flighttime CHAR(50);
    SET v_minute = DATEDIFF(minute, p_departure, p_arrival);
    SET v_hour = v_minute/60;
    SET v_minute = v_minute-(v_hour*60);

    IF v_hour<2 AND v_minute<2 THEN 
        SET v_htext = ' hour and ';
        SET v_mtext=' minute';
    ELSEIF v_hour<2 AND v_minute>1 THEN 
        SET v_htext=' hour and '; 
        SET v_mtext=' minutes';
    ELSEIF v_hour>1 AND v_minute<2 THEN 
        SET v_htext=' hours and ';
        SET v_mtext=' minute';
    ELSE 
        SET v_htext=' hours and ';
        SET v_mtext=' minutes';
    END IF;

    SET v_flighttime = CONCAT(v_hour, v_mtext, v_minute, v_mtext);

    RETURN v_flighttime;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thanks JW for the help. I had to change and improve a few more things and now it works perfectly :)